# Compiling pulseaudio on Mac OS X with CoreServices.h

Tags: macos, llvm, clang, pulseaudio

I'm trying to compile pulseaudio on Mac OS X, however by default I get lots of errors about not finding standard files like `inttypes.h`, `errno.h` or `stdio.h`. Putting `-isystem/usr/include` in `CPPFLAGS` fixes those errors, but then later on I get `fatal error: 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h' file not found`.

I've tried also adding `-framework CoreServices` and/or 
`-I/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers` but neither work.

What's the proper way of making the compiler find it?
I think I'm using clang, gcc produces even more errors.

Comment: Hey adam, did you get pulseaudio up and running on osx?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, those are the framework and include flags but if you use the correct configuration options you will find even the system includes are picked up properly.

The Makefiles will attempt to set the framework appropriately based on the `--with-mac-sysroot` and `--with-mac-version-min` attributes.

Example configuration option to specify the SDK location:

```
--with-mac-sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/ 
--with-mac-version-min=10.7
```

If you are building on Mountain lion (10.8) you still need to use the 10.7 minimum compatibility as there are headers missing in the 10.8 SDK which PulseAudio makes reference to.

You can pass the configure options to the `autogen.sh` which will run `configure` once autoconf has completed. You can try the following command which has been tested on the master branch:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local --disable-jack --disable-hal --disable-bluez --disable-avahi --with-mac-sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/ --with-mac-version-min=10.7 --disable-dbus
```

If you get m4 macro errors copy the m4 macros from aclocal into the m4 sub-directory and try again.

There are a few other problems but these are bound to be cleared up may date quickly. Adding it here as it may help someone trying to get this built.

**error: Multiprocessing.h cannot be found:**
This has been deprecated in 10.7 but the headers are still included it CoreServices and will build just change the include instruction in the file `src/pulsecore/semaphore-osx.c`.

```
-#include <Multiprocessing.h>
+#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

**error: ‘lt_*PROGRAM*_LTX_preloaded_symbols’ undeclared.**
This may be a problem compiling `src/daemon/dumpmodules.c` and can be fixed by declaring the external macro.

```
extern const lt_dlsymlist lt_preloaded_symbols[];
```

**error: gdbm.h: No such file or directory**
For some reason the default include dir is not considered by the compiler and you can add the path to the `src/Makefile` look for and set the variable `GDBM_CFLAGS`.

```
GDBM_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
```

nJoy!

Comment: And you made my day =) Tx!